# Iterating through multiple predefined ArrayLists using a method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have defined a few ArrayLists that are already populated. I have the names of all of the ones I want to iterate through in an array 'tagArrays'. Is it possible to iterate through each of them in a similar logic to mine. I know this code is not going to work however I'm not sure how the code is supposed to look. This is my attempt:

These are already populated and are defined in main method.

```
ArrayList<String> KEYWORDS = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> CUSTOMERS = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> SYSTEM_DEPS = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> MODULES = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> DRIVE_DEFS = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> PROCESS_IDS = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is the logic I'm using

```
public void genericForEachLoop(POITextExtractor te) {

        final String[] tagArrays = {"KEYWORDS", "CUSTOMERS", "SYSTEM_DEPS", "MODULES", "DRIVE_DEFS", "PROCESS_IDS"};
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<tagArrays.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tagArrays[i]);
            al = tagArrays[i];


            for (String item : al) {
                if (te.getText().contains(item)) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the for each loop to be different every time e.g. once go through KEYWORDS, then go through CUSTOMERS etc.

Comment: You cannot go from a String to a list ^^ you should use list<list<string>>

Comment: I want to use String to give al the name of an actual ArrayList so it could replace for(String item : al ) with an actual name e.g. KEYWORDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference variables with string values in Java.
What you try to do could be performed with reflection.
But I don't encourage it : it is less readable, more brittle/error prone and slower as the "classical" way.

As alternative you can provide a `varargs` of `List<String>` as last parameter of the method:

```
public void genericForEachLoop(POITextExtractor te, String[] tagArrays, List<String>... lists ) {

    int i = 0;
    for(List<String> list : lists) {    

        System.out.println(tagArrays[i]);                   
        for (String item : list) {

            if (te.getText().contains(item)) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }

        }

     i++;
    }
}
```

And invoke it in this way :

```
genericForEachLoop(te, 
   new String[]{"KEYWORDS", "CUSTOMERS", "SYSTEM_DEPS", "MODULES", "DRIVE_DEFS", "PROCESS_IDS"},
   KEYWORDS, CUSTOMERS,SYSTEM_DEPS,MODULES,DRIVE_DEFS,PROCESS_IDS);
```

Comment: Type mismatch cannot convert from element type String to List<String>

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @dsafas fsafasfsa And where  exactly have you this issue ?

Comment: for(List<String> list : lists) { <<< here

Comment: I think that you don't use the same parameter types in your code as in my sample code. Check it please.

Comment: Well... I've missed the 3 dots in the lists parameter. What does it mean exactly? That it takes multiple parameters of the same type?

Comment: Exactly. It allows to not  repeat `List<String>`. It is called : Varargs. You can have more information here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html

Comment: Great. One last question. Say I want to print 'Modules' when it iterates through this array. System.out.println("\n" + list + " found in the document: "); In this case list prints the whole array. How do I print this particular array name? list.getItem? I know how to do it on a standard for(int=0 loop but not on for each loop.

Comment: It is not specific to foreach. Actually in my sample code I don't pass the names of the lists. But you can add an additional parameter array in the method or as alternative you can also use a Map (but with a Map of List, it is in a someway a little cumbersome). I updated with the new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Rather creating **String** array you can create Array of **ArrayList**, which will help you to iterate dynamically like below.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    ArrayList<String> KEYWORDS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> CUSTOMERS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> SYSTEM_DEPS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> MODULES = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> DRIVE_DEFS = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PROCESS_IDS = new ArrayList<String>();

    final String[] tagNames = {"KEYWORDS", "CUSTOMERS", "SYSTEM_DEPS", "MODULES", "DRIVE_DEFS", "PROCESS_IDS"};
    final List<String> tagNameList=Arrays.asList(tagNames);
    final ArrayList[] tagList = { KEYWORDS, CUSTOMERS, SYSTEM_DEPS, MODULES, DRIVE_DEFS, PROCESS_IDS };

    for (ArrayList<String> list : tagList) {
        for(String str :list){
            if(str.contains(""))
            {

            }

    }
  }
```

Comment: if I do the for loop inside my method it tells me to create a local variable tagArrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following things with respect to `Java 8`. Below is the working example of your code, I have modified some of the code. Please check.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strings = {"KEYWORDS", "CUSTOMERS", "SYSTEM_DEPS", "MODULES", "DRIVE_DEFS", "PROCESS_IDS"};
        ArrayList<String> KEYWORDS = new ArrayList<String>();
        KEYWORDS.add("goto");
        ArrayList<String> CUSTOMERS = new ArrayList<String>();
        CUSTOMERS.add("Royal Lotus");
        ArrayList<String> SYSTEM_DEPS = new ArrayList<String>();
        SYSTEM_DEPS.add("MAC BOOK");
        ArrayList<String> MODULES = new ArrayList<String>();
        MODULES.add("TETS MODULE");
        ArrayList<String> DRIVE_DEFS = new ArrayList<String>();
        DRIVE_DEFS.add("TEST DRIVE");
        ArrayList<String> PROCESS_IDS = new ArrayList<String>();
        PROCESS_IDS.add("-15153213");


        Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = new HashMap<>();
        mapOfLists.put("KEYWORDS", KEYWORDS);
        mapOfLists.put("CUSTOMERS", CUSTOMERS);
        mapOfLists.put("SYSTEM_DEPS", SYSTEM_DEPS);
        mapOfLists.put("DRIVE_DEFS", DRIVE_DEFS);
        mapOfLists.put("PROCESS_IDS", PROCESS_IDS);
        mapOfLists.put("MODULES", MODULES);
        genericForEachLoop(mapOfLists, strings);
    }


    public static void genericForEachLoop(Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists, String[] listsToIterate) {
        Arrays.stream(listsToIterate).forEach((listName -> mapOfLists.get(listName).stream().forEach(str -> System.out.println(str))));
    }
}
```

I have taken out the `String[]` and providing it as an input to method so I can change it. Only those arrays where I want to iterate I can pass them. Further more building on top of @Eran's answer I am using the `Map<String, List<String>` for storing all the available `ArrayList`s.

Please modify the code as per your need. I have tried to use the `streams` and `foreach` methods from `Java8`.